# Estoy realizando un código pero no me deja actualizar

Tags: php, mysql, imagen, pdo

Estoy realizando un CRUD ya casi todo funciona pero presento un problema ya que cuando quiero actualizar no lo hace pero no me muestra ningún error ya probe usando try y catch pero no me muestra ningún problem ,  el sistema trata de un CRUD para agregar productos en un restaurante ya verifique y las variables si estan llegando desde el formulario pero no me esta realizando la actualización, tambien verifique la base de datos y no pude encontrar ningún problema tambien he probado el codigo desde otro computador y no sirve por lo cual por mi poco conocimiento puedo evidenciar que el problema esta al momento de actualizar

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>form_actualizar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../views/dist/css/add.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../views/dist/css/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    try {
        include ("../../../controller/database.php");  
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categoria_producto"); 
        $query->execute();
        $ID_PRODUCTO = $_GET["ID_PRODUCTO"];
        $productos  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE ID_PRODUCTO='$ID_PRODUCTO'");
        $productos->execute();  
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        
    }
 ?> 
 <div class="container">
        <?php
              $resultado = $productos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             foreach ($resultado as $row)?>
        <form action="../../../models/admin/productos/verificar_actualizar.php" method="post"  class="contact" id="contact"  enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="hidden" name="ID_PRODUCTO" value="<?php echo $ID_PRODUCTO?>">
            <br>
            <label for="NOMBRE_PRODUCTO">Nombre producto</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" maxlength="70" required="" class="NOMBRE_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO" name="NOMBRE_PRODUCTO"  id="NOMBRE_PRODUCTO" value="<?php echo $row["NOMBRE_PRODUCTO"];?>">
            <br>
            <label for="DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO">Descripción del producto</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO" id="DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO" class="DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO" value="<?php echo $row["DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO"];?>" cols="30" rows="10"></input>
            <br>
            <label for="CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO">Cantidad producto</label>
            <br>
            <input type="number" min="1" id="CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO" name="CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO" class="CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO" value="<?php echo $row["CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO"];?>">
            <br>
            <label for="VALOR_PRODUCTO">Valor producto</label>
            <br>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="VALOR_PRODUCTO" id="VALOR_PRODUCTO" class="VALOR_PRODUCTO" value="<?php echo $row["VALOR_PRODUCTO"];?>">
            <br>
            <label for="ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO">Categoria</label>
            <br>
            <select name="ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO" class="ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO" required="">
                <option value="">seleccionar</option>       
                <?php 
                    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach ($result as $resultado) {
                 ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $resultado['ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO']?>"><?php echo $resultado['NOMBRE_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO']?></option>
                <?php 
            }
                ?>
            </select>
            <label for="IMAGEN_PRODUCTO ">Imagen producto</label>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="IMAGEN_PRODUCTO" id="IMAGEN_PRODUCTO   "
            class="IMAGEN_PRODUCTO" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Verificar actualizar**

```
   <?php
include ("../../../controller/database.php");
if (isset($_POST['ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO'])) {
        $ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO=$_POST['ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO'];
    }
    
    $ID_PRODUCTO= $_POST['ID_PRODUCTO'];
    $NOMBRE_PRODUCTO = $_POST['NOMBRE_PRODUCTO'];
    $DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO = $_POST['DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO'];
    $CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO = $_POST['CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO'];
    $VALOR_PRODUCTO = $_POST['VALOR_PRODUCTO'];
    if ($_FILES['IMAGEN_PRODUCTO']) {
        $nombre_base = basename($_FILES['IMAGEN_PRODUCTO']["name"]);
        $nombre_final = date("m-d-y"). "-" . date("h-i-s"). "-" . $nombre_base;
        $ruta = "../../../../public/products_photo/" . $nombre_final;
        $subirimagen = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['IMAGEN_PRODUCTO']["tmp_name"], $ruta);
    }
    
            $queryProducto = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE producto SET ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO = :ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO, NOMBRE_PRODUCTO = :NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO = :DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO, CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO = :CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO, VALOR_PRODUCTO = :VALOR_PRODUCTO WHERE ID_PRODUCTO = :ID_PRODUCTO");
            $queryProducto->bindParam(":ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO",$ID_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO);
            $queryProducto->bindParam(":NOMBRE_PRODUCTO",$NOMBRE_PRODUCTO);
            $queryProducto->bindParam(":DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO",$DESCRIPCION_PRODUCTO);
            $queryProducto->bindParam(":CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO",$CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO);
            $queryProducto->bindParam(":VALOR_PRODUCTO",$VALOR_PRODUCTO);
            $queryProducto->bindParam(":ID_PRODUCTO",$ID_PRODUCTO);
            $queryProducto->execute();
      
              if ($queryProducto) {
                echo "guarda";
            }
            else{
                echo "no guardo";
            }        
            if (empty($_POST['IMAGEN_PRODUCTO'])) {
                echo "llego";
                $queryimagen = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE producto SET IMAGEN_PRODUCTO = :ruta WHERE ID_PRODUCTO = :ID_PRODUCTO");
                $queryimagen->bindParam(':ruta',$ruta);
                $queryimagen->bindParam(":ID_PRODUCTO",$ID_PRODUCTO);
                $queryimagen->execute();
                echo "valor no nullo";
            }
            else{
                echo "valor nulo";
            }
    
$pdo=null;
?> 
?>
```

**PDO conexión**

```
<?php
// Configuracion de la BD

    $servidor = "mysql:dbname=reservaya2;host=localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($servidor, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Conexion fallida " . $e->getMessage();
    }


?>
```

Tablas que se usan
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta se entienda mejor. También realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos. Indica qué hace tu código, qué resultado esperas y qué pruebas haz realizado.

Comment: en una de las primeras consultas estas tratando el id_producto como si fuera texto, cuando tu definición dice que es entero. por otra parte, nada mas empezar el codigo cojes de _GET[] de dicho valor, pero nada te garantiza que sea correcto. ahi puedes tener uno de los errores. Te aconsejo que todas las consultas las englobes en try{}catch para poder detectar este tipo de errores.

Comment: Depura tu código y dinos cuál es el resultado de esas depuraciones. Puedes usar `var_dump` para ir probando cada parte hasta identificar exactamente dónde está el problema, o bien aprender a leer el log de errores. Son técnicas de depuración sencillas que te ahorrarán horas y hasta días rompiéndote el coco para saber dónde está el problema. En tu pregunta no das ninguna pista de nada. Por ejemplo, ¿el código imprime algún mensaje, no imprime nada? Luego, tienes consultas inútiles en el código, las ejecutas, pero luego no usas esos datos para nada.

Comment: Ya depure de la forma en que me comentaste pero no me muestra ningún error los datos están llegando bien desde el formulario , cambie el ID como puedes evidenciar en el código que acabo de actualizar pero aun no se soluciona el problema no se si tengas alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el error ,el problema se encontraba en un trigger el cual le faltaba un dato para actualizar al corregir esto el sistema me funciono bien
Muchas gracias por la ayuda